How to manage oauth tokens in a telegram bot
my telegram bot is using oauth to authorize user calls to an external resource server. How can i manage user sessions?

from the telegram chat, the user is redirected to the authorization server
the user authorizes the bot and is redirected back to the bot server

for a chat id, How can I manage the oauth tokens?
